# Flutter: upload file using s3 api

Tags: flutter, image, amazon-s3, storage, cloudflare

Im trying to upload a file to Cloudflare's R2 database, which uses the s3 api. Im using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/aws_s3_upload

code so far:

```
class StorageRepository {
  Future<String> uploadFile(String path, File file) async {
    try {
      await AwsS3.uploadFile(
        accessKey: "key",
        secretKey:
            "key",
        file: file,
        bucket: "bucket",
        region: "auto",
      );
      return "https:path";
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw e; // Throw the error
    }
  }


  Future<void> uploadImage(User user, XFile image, File compressedFile) async {
    await uploadFile('${user.id}/${image.name}', compressedFile);
  }
```

However, when i try uploading, nothing happens. There are no errors, the operation completes, but it never reaches the bucket. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the problem:
https://github.com/Serdnad/aws_s3_upload/blob/master/lib/aws_s3_upload.dart#L59

You need to be able to modify the endpoint to **your R2 endpoint**.